Современный гайд во написания неубиваемого сервиса Android
Нужно сделать сервис для принятия уведомлений по SignalR. Использовать FCM не вариант. Пытался сделать по гайду 2019 года и ожидаемо тот неубиваемый сервис не проживает больше минуты даже при включенном экране. Можете или вы объяснить как его сделать или хотя бы дать ссылку на гайд который работает для современных версий api.

Ну если нужна хотя бы ссылка, то держите - Gotify - android app example. Полагаю что если разберете работу этого приложения, то проблем не будет. Так как ребята разрабатывают аналог FCM и это его клиентское приложение. Полагаю, что в нём всё настроенно как надо.
Так же стоит изучить это - Don't kill my app!. Ведь каждый уважающий себя вендор считает долгом внести свои нюансы в работу ОС Android. Кто сказал Samsung? И на этом сайте можно найти советы, как предотвратить остановку работы Вашего приложения в фоне.

Предварительно, если использовать методы как в Gotify, то на 34 апи работает. На самом деле там используется обычный сервис, который кажется просто правильно настроили в манифесте.
